# Dataframe modification consisting of multiple steps

Tags: r, dataframe, date, linear-regression

I have these two datasets that I am trying to use for linear regression. One contains daily average values (independent variables) measured from a weather [station](https://pastebin.com/jzU1LeZs).

```
date  ST5_mean  ST1_mean  ST0_mean ST10_mean Snowheight Precipitation
1 2014-10-08 11.136713 10.980278 11.333995 11.622550 0.23680556           118
2 2014-10-09  9.255580  8.727486  8.796319 11.635243 0.00000000           124
3 2014-10-10 10.297521  9.441427  9.376736 12.879920 0.00000000           108
4 2014-10-11  9.080031  9.172347  9.389281  9.372538 0.01041667           152
5 2014-10-12 10.059455  9.428875  9.392774 11.866694 0.00000000           425
.
.
.
242 2015-06-06 12.946955 11.979896 11.50326 14.060399 0.00000000           470
243 2015-06-07 12.918128 11.737031 11.17246 13.691757 0.00000000           407
244 2015-06-08 12.214410 11.779344 11.50781 12.370771 0.00000000           100
245 2015-06-09 11.271517 10.942083 10.79751 11.324122 0.00000000            19
246 2015-06-10  8.597696  9.730661 10.20789  8.181455 0.01180556           481
```

The second one is basically a logger data (dependent variable) which may have several measurements per day or none ([logger dataset](https://pastebin.com/u4vNVMnG)) ([data table jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBjuA.jpg)). I need to modify the logger data so that is consistent with the station data and can run regression on these (which means there should be 1 row per day). Logger measurements ( the "Distance" column) that happened in the same day need to be summed up so that a single value per day is obtained; so if there are for example 3 measurements for 1.2.2014, there should be a value of 2.355 (3 x 0.785). Additionally, I need to create a row for every day of the period to match the sample size of the station data. A day for which the logger has no measurements, should have value of 0. I need to perform these modifications for numerous datasets so I need to figure out a code that does this in an automatic/semi-automatic manner. Manually adding data would be absurd as datasets have up to few thousand rows. Unfortunately, I couldn't come up with anything meaningful the last few days. Any help is appreciated.

I hope I managed to explain the problem here. Let me know if you would need more clarification. Thanks in advance!

P.S  I managed the first part where I aggregate by the date and obtain the daily sums, however I am still stuck at creating a row for every day in the given time period and assigning 0 for the "distance" variable. This is what I have so far.

```
startTime <- as.Date("2014-10-08")
endTime <- as.Date("2015-06-10")
start_end <- c(startTime,endTime)
startTime <- as.Date("2014-10-08")
logger1 <- read.csv("124106_106.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")
logger1$date <- as.Date(logger1$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")
logger1_sum <- aggregate (logger1$Distance, by = list(logger1$date), FUN = sum, na.rm=TRUE)"
names (logger1_sum) <- c("date", "distance")

head(logger1_sum, 5)
       date distance
1 2014-10-02    1.570
2 2014-10-03    3.140
3 2014-10-08    3.925
4 2014-10-23    9.420
5 2014-10-24    3.925

tail(logger1_sum, 5)
        date distance
45 2015-05-26    1.570
46 2015-05-27    1.570
47 2015-05-28    1.570
48 2015-06-10    0.785
49 2015-07-06    1.570
```

Comment: Please use `dput()` to include the original data. It's cumbersome for us to work without a minimal.

Comment: Have you checked the links that are provided? These are pastebin links with dput() output. Let me know if I have done it wrong.

Comment: Here they are once again. Station data: https://pastebin.com/jzU1LeZs Logger data: https://pastebin.com/u4vNVMnG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the job. I use the **data.table** package which makes joins super easy and fast.

For brevity, I do not report your data so you will see the code starting as if the `logger` and `station` data.frame are already in the environment. The code does the following: it sums the columns `Distance` and `AccuDist` (assuming those two columns are the one important) by the column `date`, which is the one correctly formatted in `Date` class.

Then, I set the merging keys with the function `setkey()`. If you want to read more about how to joins work and how to perform them with data.table, please refer to [this link](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html). If you instead want to know more about **data.table** in general, you can refer to the official website [here](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/).

I then define the data.table `final` which comes out of *right outer* join. This way, I will retain all the observations (i.e., rows) in the object `station`.

```r
library(data.table)

# this converts the two data.frame in data.table by reference
setDT(logger)
setDT(station)

# sum Distance by date
logger_summed <- logger[ , .( sum_Distance = sum(Distance), 
                              sum_AccuDist = sum(AccuDist)), by = date]

> head(logger_summed)
##       date    sum_Distance sum_AccuDist
## 1: 2014-10-02        1.570        2.355
## 2: 2014-10-03        3.140       14.130
## 3: 2014-10-08        3.925       35.325
## 4: 2014-10-23        9.420      164.850
## 5: 2014-10-24        3.925      102.050
## 6: 2014-10-25        2.355       70.650


setkey( logger_summed, date )
setkey( station, date )

final <- logger_summed[ station ]
final[ is.na(sum_Distance), `:=` ( sum_Distance = 0, sum_AccuDist = 0) ]

> final
##           date sum_Distance sum_AccuDist  ST5_mean  ST1_mean  ST0_mean ST10_mean Snowheight Precipitation
##  1: 2014-10-08        3.925       35.325 11.136713 10.980278 11.333995 11.622550 0.23680556           118
##  2: 2014-10-09        0.000        0.000  9.255580  8.727486  8.796319 11.635243 0.00000000           124
##  3: 2014-10-10        0.000        0.000 10.297521  9.441427  9.376736 12.879920 0.00000000           108
##  4: 2014-10-11        0.000        0.000  9.080031  9.172347  9.389281  9.372538 0.01041667           152
##  5: 2014-10-12        0.000        0.000 10.059455  9.428875  9.392774 11.866694 0.00000000           425
## ---                                                                                                      
## 242: 2015-06-06        0.000        0.000 12.946955 11.979896 11.503257 14.060399 0.00000000           470
## 243: 2015-06-07        0.000        0.000 12.918128 11.737031 11.172462 13.691757 0.00000000           407
## 244: 2015-06-08        0.000        0.000 12.214410 11.779344 11.507812 12.370771 0.00000000           100
## 245: 2015-06-09        0.000        0.000 11.271517 10.942083 10.797510 11.324122 0.00000000            19
## 246: 2015-06-10        0.785      115.395  8.597696  9.730661 10.207893  8.181455 0.01180556           481
```

Does this help?

Comment: You sir are amazing. Also thanks for the tutorial links. I will definitely have a look at them as I am currently not fully understanding how your code works but I will get there. Thank you!